# Where is the "Service" in a Service Reference?

Tags: c#, .net, wcf, web-services

I've been experimenting with moving a web service from the old fashioned asmx technology to the newer WCF, and I think I'm missing something fairly basic about how to reference it.

When I choose, "Add Web Reference" and point to the WSDL I get all of the relevant classes from the wsdl defined, plus a class with static methods to call them, such as this:

```
TrackService service = new TrackService() { Url = "https://gateway.fedex.com:443/web-services" };
```

When I choose "Add Service Reference" I get almost all of the same classes generated, such as TrackRequest, TrackReply and so on, but no TrackService class. So I can build up the request object, but don't know how to invoke the service. I tried searching through the generated classes for "service" or "client" but can't find anything.

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms733881(v=vs.110).aspx You might be looking for a class that inherits from System.ServiceModel.ClientBase<ITrackService>

Comment: Where do you see any static methods?

Answer (score 1):

It was there, but strangely named as FedexTrackService.TrackPortTypeClient

Comment: That's not such a strange name considering that what you created is a client.

Comment: Yes, but TrackPortTypeClient? I should think they should call it TrackClient or something more logical like that.

Comment: Yup!  That one left me scratching my head.  I thought it had something to do with a WCF port or some communications channel thingy,  Very confusing and neither MS or FedEx documents help.  It's stuff like this that makes me thing the singularity and self-driving cars will have to cross a gigantic software hurdle.